# POST:ing file from electron main.js to webserver

Tags: node.js, upload, electron, webserver

I've been searching for well over an hour now and all I get is browser-to-server code and it's so frustrating that everything revolves around a NodeJS app being a web server that a website uploads to.

Is there any way to upload a file from a NodeJS app to a webserver including some body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
var formdata = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    file1: fs.createReadStream(path_to_file)
}

request.post({url: 'http://127.0.0.1/upload', formData: formdata},
    function (err, resp, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error!');
        } else {
            console.log('URL: ' + body);
        }
    }
)
```